# Rails 3 build_association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to create something along the lines of [How to Implement Basic Defensio Spam Protection in Rails](http://rpheath.com/posts/427-how-to-implement-basic-defensio-spam-protection-in-rails) but I'm running into a problem. In the article they have something like:

```
def self.init(attributes)
    self.new(clean!(attributes))
end

private

def self.clean!(attrs)
    returning({}) do |cleansed_attributes|
        attrs.each do |key, value|
            cleansed_attributes.merge!(key.to_s.underscore => value)
        end
    end
end
```

They are then calling `DefensioResponse.init`. In my case however I had it setup a a little bit differently. I'm calling `comment.build_defensio()` (my model is called Defensio instead of DefensioResponse) and it appears that `self.init` is never being called. How should I change the above code block in order to have it work w/ `comment.build_defensio()`?

**For More Information**

If you need to look at any of the source code I have it hosted over on [Github](http://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web).

Basically what I'm doing is submitting a comment (Skatepark::Comment), after it successfully saves `DefensioJob` gets enqueued w/ `Delayed::Job.enqueue(DefensioJob.new(self.id))`. Inside of the defensio job is where I'm attempting to create and save a new `Skatepark::Comment::Defensio` record.

Comment: It would help if you could post the relevant parts of your model.

Comment: @zeteic - I've updated my question to include a little better explanation as well as a link to my entire project which is over on GitHub. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override initializer of model, like this

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  super(clean!(attributes))
end
```